# Extjs style radiogroup to right of toolbar grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, toolbar

I have gridpanel and radiogroup on toolbar like **http://jsfiddle.net/RHxU3/**

```
tbar: [
    {
                xtype: 'radiogroup',         
                columns: 3,
                style: 'float: right !important;',
                defaults: {
                    name: 'rating' 
                },
                items: [{
                    inputValue: '0',
                    width: 60,
                    boxLabel: 'a'
                }, {
                    inputValue: '1',
                    width: 60,
                    boxLabel: 'b'

                }, {
                    inputValue: '2',
                    width: 60,
                    boxLabel: 'c'
                }]
        }
    ]
```

I want my radiogroup will be right of toolbar. like
[image]

I using below code but not working. How can i do that thanks.

```
style: 'float: right !important;',
```

Comment: add `'->'` before 1st toolbar item

Comment: it's working thank u. how u know that :)

Comment: read the docs. refer http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar & http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Fill